# Reloading janrain widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, janrain

I have the Janrain social login widget in place on my site and am processing authentication requests with AJAX.

In certain situations, even though there is a successful login with the social site (say, Twitter), I want to prevent the login on my website.

When this happens, the Janrain widget is stuck saying "Loading...", even though there's nothing more to do.  However, I would like for the user to be able to try logging in again through another site (say, Facebook).

Currently, the only way to make this happen is to refresh the entire page.  Not necessarily convenient, but not a large burden either.  Still, I would like to avoid requiring this.

Here is my code - almost an exact copy/paste of what Janrain provides:

```
//Initialization of the widget on page load
(function() {
    if (typeof window.janrain !== 'object') window.janrain = {};
    window.janrain.settings = {};

    janrain.settings.tokenUrl = THE_URL
    janrain.settings.tokenAction='event';

    function isReady() { janrain.ready = true; };
    if (document.addEventListener) {
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", isReady, false);
    } else {
      window.attachEvent('onload', isReady);
    }

    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.id = 'janrainAuthWidget';

    if (document.location.protocol === 'https:') {
      e.src = 'https://rpxnow.com/js/lib/(domain)/engage.js';
    } else {
      e.src = 'http://widget-cdn.rpxnow.com/js/lib/(domain)/engage.js';
    }

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s);
})();

//Handler for AJAX authentication
function janrainWidgetOnload(){
    janrain.events.onProviderLoginToken.addHandler(function(tokenResponse) {
        $.ajax({
            //(blah blah blah)
        });
    });
}

<!-- Widget is inserted into this named DIV -->
<div id="janrainEngageEmbed"></div>
```

I've tried making the initialization function a named function which is then called explicitly when the page loads.  Even though that works for the initialization of the widget, calling it again fails - even after making a jQuery call to kill all the HTML inside the target DIV where the widget is inserted.

Ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are yet to register localhost url with Janrain. Try going to Application Settings under the Deployment tab and adding your local url to it. Something like localhost.

Then change your token url to your landing page. like ...

```
janrain.settings.tokenUrl = 'https://localhost:8000/home'
```

Good luck!